# POSTMAN standalone application does not show the response code name of an API call

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, postman

I have deployed a sample REST API (spring boot application) on Azure Web app for containers using docker container and tested some API calls using POSTMAN standalone application. I observed that the response does not display the code name. Please refer the image below. 
[image]

When the same API call was invoked by the POSTMAN browser extension the status code and the code name both were displayed as expected. Please refer the second image below.
[image]

Is this a problem of POSTMAN, the way it represent the response ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using the standalone application and am seeing the full status

Comment: Interestingly, when trying the same URL from your image, I get the same response you get.

Comment: Yep I get the same - If you add this to the `Tests` tab of the native app `console.log('The status code: ' + pm.response.code')` and 
`console.log('The status message: ' + pm.response.status)` you will see what's being returned (basicaly what populates that part of the UI)

Comment: @Fishcake - same in the sense "no" status code name? only the status code 404 ?

Comment: @DannyDainton - yup...I have tried that...and it returns "" empty string. Any insights on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you raised an issue directly with Postman and stated the differences, it seems like the web app processes what’s been sent back in a different way but it could be anything really. It’s not really something that people here can provide a solution for, in my opinion.

Comment: @DannyDainton as these observations are made on Azure web apps I have opened a ticket on Azure Support. I will create a ticket in the POSTMAN as well. Thank you

Comment: @Sathya - Yes I get a blank status calling your site. However I have tested on an Azure website of my own and do not get the issue so I'm suspecting that it may be Spring boot.

Comment: @Fishcake - yes...there is that assumption as well. But I have tried deploying the same spring boot application on a Azure VM just as it is (without using Azure Web App) and tried accessing it which worked as expected. However I have created a POSTMAN support ticket on this and will update the findings here as well

Comment: Did you find anything else out about this?

Comment: nope...wrote to both Microsoft support and POSTMAN support ... I haven't got a direct answer from any of the support teams...still the tickets are open and I hope one of them will come up with an answer soon